# How does method references work under hood when there are multiple arguments

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

How does compiler ensure that equivalent lambda for below statement

```
BinaryOperator<String> concatOperator = String::concat;
```

is

```
BinaryOperator<String> concatOperator = (resultString, inputString) -> resultString.concat(inputString);
```

and not

```
BinaryOperator<String> concatOperator = (resultString, inputString) -> inputString.concat(resultString);
```

Comment: Assuming, there had to be a choice between one implementation over the other. The authors chose former over the latter to be represented as method references. Given that the language adapts to LtoR syntax, makes it more compatible with existing practices and code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had same belief, but just wanted to have confirmation on this implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour is well-documented in the JLS

> ### [15.13.3. Run-Time Evaluation of Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3)
>
> If the compile-time declaration is an instance method, then **the target reference is the first formal parameter of the invocation method**. Otherwise, there is no target reference.
>
> If the compile-time declaration is an instance method, then **the arguments to the method invocation expression (if any) are the second and subsequent formal parameters of the invocation method**. Otherwise, the arguments to the method invocation expression are the formal parameters of the invocation method.

and it seems reasonable and intuitive. If you take a method with arity `n` (`n > 2`), it becomes obvious that the target reference should be the first parameter, not the last, not the one in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

The line of code using method references is categorized under the [types of method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) as -

*Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type*

where the first lambda argument is inferred as an object of type `String` on which the method named `concat` is invoked with the parameter value equivalent to the second lambda argument. In the above case as:

```
BinaryOperator<String> concatOperator = (result, input) -> result.concat(input);
```